# Remove $ sign in front of price in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

If i have a column that has values with $ sign in front of them ( $10 for example ) how can i remove the dollar sign and convert the column to decimal?

Comment: What is the data type for the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace()`:

```
select replace(col, '$', '')::numeric
```